# Is it possible to emulate keyed state with operator state?

Tags: apache-flink

Just for the sake of experimenting and learning. Let's assume that we have a
keyed process function using keyed state and we want to rewrite it using
operator state. The question is, would it be possible to keep the exact
same behaviour? For example, one could use operator union list state and
then setup a timer to automatically remove the state not used within a given
time...that would probably work but I'd rather prefer a way to know which
elements of the union list state to use right after a recovery/restore,
discarding the others, depending on the set of keys the current operator
instance has been assigned. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically, yes, I think this is possible to some extent. You would have to give up all the things that require a KeyedStream, such as timers, and the RocksDB state backend. And performance would suffer.

As for the question of determining which key groups (and ultimately, which keys) are handled by a specific instance, see these mailing list threads:

[How can I find out which key group belongs to which subtask](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-find-out-which-key-group-belongs-to-which-subtask-td32032.html)
[Use keyBy to deterministically hash each record to a processor/task/slot](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Use-keyBy-to-deterministically-hash-each-record-to-a-processor-task-slot-td16483.html)